# Sprintf language error

Tags: database, printf

i want to make a function for my laguage

im using system of language form database

some words i have to redefina in script but i cant find the way

my code:

```
$str = "I'm %s from %s"; // string from database

$tre = 'ex3m,Albania';  // replacements
$tre = explode(',',$tre); // trying to convert replacements to strings separated with commas

sprintf($str, $tre);
```

resoults:

```
Warning: sprintf(): Too few arguments
```

and the result i want is:

```
I'm ex3m from Albania
I'm {ex3m} from {Albania}
```

can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`sprintf`](http://php.net/sprintf) takes a variable number of arguments, not an array. Use [`vsprintf`](http://php.net/vsprintf):

```
$result = vsprintf($str, $tre);
```

Comment: @ex3m.al: No problem! If this worked for you, you can accept the answer by clicking the empty green checkbox on the left.